# webview not work for local html file in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local webView = native.newWebView( 0, 50, 320, 430 )
webView.anchorX = 0;
webView.anchorY = 0;
print("***************************************files/");
print("files/"..data[1].name..".html");
local htmlFile = "files/"..data[1].name..".html"

--Ancient Egypt
webView:request( "files/"..data[1].name..".html", system.ResourceDirectory );
webView:addEventListener( "urlRequest", webListener );
```

I have to use in corona then its not open my local html file. How to use better in corona?

Answer (score 0):

The webView is not supported on Simulator.

Try also simply using below while bulding the app with "files" fodler in your code directory:

```
webView:request( "files/"..data[1].name..".html");
```

instead of

```
webView:request( "files/"..data[1].name..".html", system.ResourceDirectory );
```

Try using data[1] instead of data[1].name to see if it returns the right value.